# Retornar valores Select Multiple

Tags: php, select, sql-update

tudo bem com todos vocês, eu espero que sim.

Eu tenho uma dúvida e não estou conseguindo avançar com o meu código. Então vamos lá

Eu tenho uma tela de cadastrado com um select multiple com os dados abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control " id="restriction_details" name="restriction_details[]" data-msg="Selecione o estado" size="10" multiple="multiple">
 <﻿option value="">Selecione</option>
 <option value="1" >A - Obrigatório o uso de lentes corretivas</option>
 <option value="2" >B - Obrigatório o uso de prótese auditiva</option>
 <option value="3" >C - Obrigatório o uso de acelerador à esquerda</option>
 <option value="4" >D - Obrigatório o uso de veículo com transmissão automática</option>
 <option value="5" >E - Obrigatório o uso de empunhadura/manopla/pômo no volante</option>
 <option value="6" >F - Obrigatório o uso de veículo com direção hidráulica</option>
 <option value="7" selected="selected">G - Obrigatório o uso de veículo com embreagem manual ou com automaçào de embreagem ou com transmissão automática</option>
 <option value="8" >H - Obrigatório o uso de acelerador e freio manual</option>
 <option value="9" >I - Obrigatório o uso de adaptação dos comandos de painel ao volante</option>
 <option value="10" >J - Obrigatório o uso de adaptação dos comandos de painel para os membros inferiores e/ou outras partes do corpo</option>
 <option value="11" >K - Obrigatório o uso de veículo com prolongamento da alavanca de câmbio e/ou almofadas (fixas) de compensação de altura e/ou profundidade</option>
 <option value="12"﻿ >L - Obrigatório o uso de veículo com pronlogadores dos pedais e elevação do assoalho e/ou almofadas fixas de compensação de altura e/ou profundidade</option>
 <option value="13" >M - Obrigatório o uso de motocicleta com pedal de câmbio adaptado</option>
 <option value="14" >N - Obiragatório o uso de motocicleta com pedal do freio traseiro adaptado</option>
 <option value="15" >O -﻿ Obrigatório o uso de motocicleta com manopla do freio dianteiro adaptada</option>
 <option value="16" >P - Obrigatório o uso de motocicleta com manopla de embreagem adaptada</option>
 <option value="17" >Q﻿ - Obrigatório o uso de motocicleta com carro lateral ou triciclo</option>
 <option value="18" >R ﻿- Obrigatório o uso de motoneta com carro lateral ou triciclo</option>
 <option value="19" >S - Obrigatório o uso de motocicleta com automação de troca de marchas</option>
 <option value="20" >T ﻿- Vedado dirigir em rodovias e vias de trânsito rápido</option>
 <option value="21" >U - Vedado dirigir após o pôr-do-sol</option>
 <option value="22" >V - Obrigatório o uso de capacete de segurança com viseira protetora sem limitação de campo visual</option>
 <option value="23" >W - Aposentado por invalidez</option>
 <option value="24" >X ﻿- Outras restrições</option>
 <option value="25" >Y - Surdo (Restrição impressa como X na CNH)</option>
 <option value="26" >Z - Visão Monocular (Restrição impressa como X na CNH)</option>
```

﻿﻿﻿

Ao inserir o mesmo no banco de dados eu guardo dentro um TABELA chamada de restrição cujo tem os seguintes campos

ID
CLIENTE_ID 
Restrição = (Armazena somente o Value do Select)

A Tabela de Clientes e Restrição estão relacionadas.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Agora estou criando a página para editar os dados e preciso trazer esse SELECT MULTIPLE acima com os dados cadastrados, quando eu pesquiso o ID CLIENTE ele precisa me retornar o campo select já com os valores cadastrados, mas como fazer isso?

Eu até pensei criar um array para fazer o select multiple já com todos os dados, e depois que criar a query SQL usando o WHERE para pegar o código do cliente. Mas o que quero é que ele me exiba a lista novamente agora só com os dados retornado.
Como fazer isso?

Obrigado a todos e um excelente fim de Sabado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

vai ter que popular com javascript,
alguma coisa assim:

```
<script>
var select = $('#restriction_details');
<?php
  foreach($arraySelected as $opcao){ ?>
   select.append($("<option selected></option>").val(<?=$opcao?>));
<?php }?>
</script>
```

Ai tem que tratar com suas variaveis.